# How can the lyapunov exponents for the Mandelbrot Set be computed?

Tags: numerical-methods, complex-numbers, chaos-theory

I am trying to find a way to calculate the Lyapunov exponents of the Mandelbrot set.
There are some very nice diagrams that you can find on Flickr of a plot of the Lyapunov exponents of the Mandelbrot set, leading to a much higher detail in the structure of the set.

I would like to do this as well and have found the definition of the Lyapunov Exponent but I cannot find a good paper or documentation on how to calculate the Lyapunov Exponent for the M-Set. Especially the derivative of the function $z[n+1] = z^n + c$ with regards to the starting position $x_0$ is what I cannot figure out.

Do I have to use an approximation for this derivative? If yes, which one? If no, how can these exponents be calculated for the Mandelbrot set.

Many thanks!

Lukas M.

PS: I am a hobby mathematician, but mainly an engineer. A description in terms of an algorithm would greatly help. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: You can't define the derivative for a discrete process. That does not mean there is no equivalent to the Lyapunov exponent, but it certainly means that you can't use the definition you have at hand.

Comment: [Here's a definition for the maximal Lyapunov exponent for discrete systems.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent#Definition_of_the_maximal_Lyapunov_exponent)

Comment: Other point, the formula to generate the Mandelbrot set is $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov you said you cannot define the derivative for a discrete process. then again the definition you provide for the maximal lyapunov exponent requires a derivative.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the derivative of the iterated process, but the derivative of the map $f$ which is being iterated. And that is something different altogether. But I maybe misunderstood what you meant initially.

Comment: @Raskolnikov and is there already a derivative for the Mandelbrot map defined?

Comment: But the map is just a quadratic function $z^2+c$. Hence the derivative is $2z$. Although I'm not sure if that is the derivative what they mean in the definition of the wikipage.

Comment: @Raskolnikov I have the strange feeling that the derivative of a complex function is not the same as the derivative of a real valued function. You could of course split the complex number up into two parts, creating the derivative of this vector function and using that to compute the exponent. then again the exponent definition is not valid, as this is only given for real valued maps and not vector functions.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lambda_f(z_0) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left ( \ln\left|f'(z_i)\right | \right )
$$

where :

$$
f'(x) = \frac{d}{dz}f_c(z) = 2z
$$
means first derivative of f with respect to z

see :
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/Mandelbrot_set
for references